# How to find the TeamCity build that contains a given commit to git?

Tags: git, teamcity

Context: a git commit is detected by TeamCity and an automatic build is started.

Given the git commit hash, and the TeamCity configuration, how do you find the build in the configuration that contains the commit, without having to inspect each build manually via the web UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you label each revision that you build (or at least each revision that builds green, which I generally want to do for other reasons), and include the build number in the label (I have "build-%system.build.number%" in "Version Control Settings" -> "Labeling pattern" for the project that I'm looking at right now), it's just a matter of finding the first tag after the commit of interest.

Comment: That's the way to go. And then use: git tag --contains <commit> to list out the builds.

Comment: Loooks like a workaround for 100 miles away from TeamCity. I wish i had to use "find by commit" TeamCity function.

Comment: Interesting! How to find the latest N commits that went into a specified build number?

Answer (score 11):

In TeamCity 9 there is a clean way to a get the build(s) which contains given git commit. Just use filtering!

```
Build Configuration -> Change Log tab -> Advanced search -> revision: <your git revision>
```

Comment: Very useful, but it doesn't seem to find merge commits, unfortunately.

Comment: I'm using TeamCity 2018.1.2 and this advanced search has found the merge commit I was looking for